# Using a select for navigation instead of tabs?

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation, tabs, select

Is a select box appropriate to control navigation on a page? For user profiles, I'm considering putting a select box in the header to change views, so a user can select from 'About', 'Calendar', 'Contact' etc. The other option would be to obviously use tabs.

I like the idea of the select, because it takes up much less room. Is this an appropriate use?

Comment: If you're going to use a select, I'm assuming that's going to stay no matter what viewport the user arrives on (Desktop, tablet, phone, etc)? The problem with this approach is users wont be able to tell on arrival what the site has to offer. Even from a mobile perspective, the user has to still click in order to "see more" even if you choose to use a hamburger menu in any mobile responsive design, which means there will be two tiers of hidden information (the dropdown being the less useful).

Comment: @Majo0od That's true, the select would obscure what's available. This is especially critical for my app in particular.

Comment: "Saving space" isn't always the right solution. Primarily when we talk about the main navigation, showing everything is vital, because users need to know where to go.

Answer (score 2):

Select is not appropriate for navigation. You should provide all items visible, this way its easier to reach them for the user, and user must not click every time he wants to see whats in menu.

Answer (score 0):

You might employ a hamburger menu if space is at a premium. It's more communicative of navigation than a select menu.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a select box appropriate to control navigation on a page?

For desktop No. For mobile Yes. IMHO. I have done some tests and found this approach appealing.

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

Mobile:

[image: Mobile]

Live: https://static.go4webdev.org/deploy